# How can I pass a file to an executable, the way dragging-n-dropping allows?

Tags: excel, vba, shell

Consider I have the following :

- An Excel workbook, which generates a .txt file (through a macro).
- An executable file (`.exe`) which can parse this .txt file.

My objective here is to program the following algorithm :

- Get the user to enter his data in the worksheets.
- Prepare the `.txt` file according to what the user entered.
- Pass the newly created `.txt` file to the external program (`.exe`).

Now, the first two steps work perfectly, I can generate the proper `.txt` file. The problem comes when I need to pass it to the external executable. Here's what's tried and observed :

- Calling `Shell()` with : `"C:\path\to\program.exe" "C:\path\to\file.txt"` (EDIT : *as a single string*) ; simple enough, yet this does not work : the external `.exe` doesn't like being given a path. I have also tried entering the command directly into Windows' `Execute` utility : same. **It seems like giving the program a path to the `.txt` isn't enough.**
- Dragging the `.txt` file onto the program's `.exe` works! The external executable does its work correctly. **Here, it is as if I had passed the "file" to the program, not just its path**. As a UNIX user, this sound like quite a non-sense to me (without a notion of stream or pipe), so maybe I'm missing something here...

Now, here's my question. When dragging-n-dropping a file onto an executable, how does Windows "translate" it ? Obviously, it does not translate it to *"pass the file's path as the program's first parameter"*. How can I pass the `.txt` file to the executable program, without just passing its path like I did with my first `Shell()` call ?

A few other notes :

- I am using Microsoft Office Excel 2010 on Windows 7. *I'm already dying from it, thanks for your concern.*
- This external `.exe` I'm talking about cannot be modified and recompiled (which would be awesome), that's the tricky thing. I have to use it as it is, whatever happens.
- Using `Shell()` is not a problem, if you give me the proper command/fix. I have also tried calling `Run` on a `VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")`, same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, here's my question. When dragging-n-dropping a file onto an
>   executable, how does Windows "translate" it ? Obviously, it does not
>   translate it to "pass the file's path as the program's first
>   parameter".

It does exactly that. Create a batch file:

```
@echo off
echo You passed parameter: %1
pause
```

Save it as `test.bat`

Browse to it in file explorer, and drag/drop something onto it:

[image: Example output of batch file]

Previous comments:

Looks like you have to send the path and filename as one parameter, e.g.:

```
Shell("C:\path\to\program.exe C:\path\to\file.txt")
```

or if the paths have spaces in them, maybe:

```
Shell("""C:\path\to\program.exe"" ""C:\path\to\file.txt""")
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a3a3d1a7-5c9a-4c91-ab96-41d367eac2fb/using-shell-function-in-vba-how-do-i-pass-a-parameter?forum=accessdev

Comment: The `Shell()` routine has only one argument allocated to the command, I couldn't pass it as two even if I wanted to. I have tried putting extra spaces, extra quotes, everything ; it wouldn't lead me anywhere. Plus : passing the file path to the program using the Windows `Execute` utility wouldn't have failed if the problem was strictly related to the `Shell()` call ;)

Comment: @JohnWHSmith Well, I read "calling shell() with two distinct strings" different to how you intended. I have updated my answer with a demonstration that Explorer drag-drop does just pass the file path as the first parameter. Also the link in my answer is people doing what you are trying - calling a program with a path, and a file with a path as a first parameter, using Shell(). Is there any chance you have something weird in the filename - more than 255 character paths, or odd characters? Can you post a real example instead of an edited  "C:\path\to\program.exe" ?

Comment: About most recent edits : I'll give it a try tomorrow, I no longer have a Windows available today. I'll think about accepting the answer if it leads to a fix. Thank you for the demonstration though! (actually, this may have a connection with some *current directory* difference, I may need some `ChDir` first, as I don't know how the `.exe` handles paths internally). About my example : I tried with even simpler paths like `C:\myexe.exe` and `C:\mytext.txt`, no difference.

Comment: Accepted answer. Even though it did not directly solve my problem (it **was** a `ChDir` problem, the `.exe` was even more demanding than I thought), your answer still corresponds to "how does Windows translate Drag-n-Drop?" ;)